# jQuery event doesn't work at new created element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I take img element with a class ".follow", then I hide it and replace it with a new created element button with a class `.followbutton`. After `mouseout` event I take this new created button element, hide it and replace it with a new created img element with a class `.follow`. Finally I have new element img with the same attributes which were initially. But now `mouseenter` doesn't work, and I don't figure it out why.

```js
$(".follow")
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(150, function() {
            var init = this;
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var t = document.createTextNode("Follow");
            btn.appendChild(t);
            btn.className = "followbutton";
            $(btn).hide();
            $(this).replaceWith(btn);
            $(".followbutton").show(150);
            $(".followbutton").on("mouseout", function() {
                var imgback = $("<img />", {
                   class: "follow",
                   src: "img/remove.png",
                }).hide();
                $(this).hide(150);
                $(this).replaceWith(imgback);
                $(".follow").show(150);
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Follow</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <img src="img/remove.png" class="follow">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you lost your listener on `.follow` when creating a new `img` tag and replace it your document. You have to use a event delegation instead.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".follow", function() { /* ... */ });
```

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".follow", function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(150, function() {
            var init = this;
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var t = document.createTextNode("Follow");
            btn.appendChild(t);
            btn.className = "followbutton";
            $(btn).hide();
            $(this).replaceWith(btn);
            $(".followbutton").show(150);
            $(".followbutton").on("mouseout", function() {
                var imgback = $("<img />", {
                   class: "follow",
                   src: "img/remove.png",
                }).hide();
                $(this).hide(150);
                $(this).replaceWith(imgback);
                $(".follow").show(150);
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <title>Follow</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <img src="img/remove.png" class="follow">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are attaching event to newly added item, nothing would happen. This is because of the directly bound event handler that we attached previously. Direct events are only attached to elements at the time the .on() method is called. Please refer below link for example and clear understanding.

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate for such situations. It will solve your problem of event attachment to the element. Try below code.

```
$(document).delegate(".follow","mouseenter", function() {
    //YOUR CODE
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method. So you really should not use `delegate` anymore.